# When inheriting UIView and creating an instance for the new class, it does not create a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, addsubview

I have created a new class inheriting UIView. When I create an instance of the new class, the view does not seem to be created.
This is my class.

```
class QuestionView: UIView {

    var metrics : [String : CGFloat] = [:]

    override init(frame : CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here I have created an instance of this class to have the following values

**x** = 0, **y** = middle of the screen, **width** = as wide as the screen, 
 **height** = 400

```
class mainView : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var questionView = QuestionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400))
        self.view.addSubView(questionView)
    }
}
```

I find no view being created.

Comment: Do you mean that the view is not visible on the screen? You need to add it the view hierarchy first.

Comment: Yeah, the view is not visible. @pckill

Comment: Are you using xib? you need to load it first

Comment: No @Shruti I am not.

Comment: can you check if your view is in foreground or it may be hiding behind any other subview. You can use the debugger to check the view hierarchy

Comment: Can u show the po of your view after it is initialised

Answer (score 0):

Add subview(questionView) in `mainView` class in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.view.addSubview(questionView)
```

you can also test the view by setting the background color

```
questionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

[image]

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh, do you have any `xib` associated with QuestionView?

Comment: No I am not using.

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh, I tried your code and it is working. Do you have another view embedded in `mainView ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add all views created programmatically in `viewDidLayoutSubView` like below

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      var questionView = QuestionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400))
self.view.addSubView(questionView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to get the view in front, use `bringSubviewToFront` function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let questionView = QuestionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400))
        self.view.addSubview(questionView)

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(questionView)

    }
```